# Python : Handling an error by provoking it. Is this good practice?

Tags: python, logging, error-handling

I have a Python application for which I have a logger.

At different steps of the execution, the application must read various input files. Input files which can have different information but are all read through the same function.

One of the particular information I am looking at is one called `computation_id` and MUST be present  in one of the file but can be absent from all others.

And I am interested to know what is a correct way of handling this situation. Currently I am handling it like this :

```
def input_reading(filename):
   results = {}
   [...]
   
   try:
     results['computation_id'] = read_computation_id()
   except KeyError:
     pass   
   [...]

   return results
```

so if the `computation_id` is absent from the file being read, the code shall keep running. However, at some point, I will need this computation id and therefore I need to check if it was correctly read from the file where I expect to find it.

I actually need this value far down the code. But running the code up to this point (which takes some time) to then fail is wasted computation time. So my idea is to check for this value as soon as I can and handle the error the following way :

```
def specifc_file_read(filename):
   [...]

   results = input_reading('my_file')
   try:
     results['computation_id']
   except KeyError:
     logger.exception('no computation id provided, aborting')
     raise SystemExit('no computation id provided, aborting')

   [...]
```

Is this good practice ?

I have a feeling it's not since I need to write special code lines to check for the error "as soon as I can" in the code to avoid wasting computation time.

Since I don't have much experience with error handling, I want to know if this is good practice or not in order not to keep bad habits.

Comment: Are you reading all the files at the same time? Or processing them on demand?

Comment: I process them on demand

Comment: I'd say it makes sense to have a table with file id and a bool value such as `has_computation_id`. Or some sort of cache.

Comment: I would check if the key is available in the function that consumes it, and if not - throw the exception.

Comment: The way the code is architected, I can't do it like that. Indeed, some of the files won't have that key and that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to what you prefer, imo.
I think that would be more readable

```
if 'computation_id' not in results: raise ...
```

although if you want to check if it's available in any file before you begin some heavy data processing, you could to

```
for f in get_files():
    if 'computation_id' in f:
        break
else:
    raise SystemExit
```

So it will raise `SystemExit` if it didn't break, so if it's not available in at least one file.